# How to show the term name in the URL instead of a term id for faceted searches?

Tags: 7, search

Using Search API and Facet API, how can you set up exposed facets or indexing so that you can create better URLs instead of something like:

`?q=field_myfield_categories:123,456,789`

I would rather show:

`?q=categories:foo,bar,baz`

I am using Drupal 7.54, Search API, Search API Solr, and Facet API.

Note that taxonomy isn't the only thing I would like to rewrite in the URL, so if there is a way to deal with this in Facet API + Search API short of writing everything custom, I would like to know.